# How can I check the current `-o defaults` set of default `mount` options?

Tags: linux, debian, mount

`man mount` describes `-o defaults` as including the following set of default `mount` options: `rw`, `suid`, `dev`, `exec`, `auto`, `nouser`, and `async`.

Will `mount` options enabled/disabled in the system kernel be added/removed from the `-o defaults` set of default `mount` options? Does the same apply to filesystem-specific default options?

How can I check the current `-o defaults` set of default `mount` options by inspecting `/proc/mounts`? It only lists all currently mounted filesystems.

```
man mount

FILESYSTEM-INDEPENDENT MOUNT OPTIONS
       Some of  these  options  are  only  useful  when  they  appear  in  the
       /etc/fstab file.

       Some  of  these  options could be enabled or disabled by default in the
       system kernel.  To  check  the  current  setting  see  the  options  in
       /proc/mounts.   Note that filesystems also have per-filesystem specific
       default mount options (see for  example  tune2fs  -l  output  for  extN
       filesystems).

        ...

        defaults
          Use  the default options: rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and
          async.

          Note that the real set of all default mount options  depends  on
          kernel  and  filesystem type.  See the beginning of this section
          for more details.
```

Comment: `-o defaults` is something internal to the `mount(8)` utility. What has `/proc/mounts` to do with it? Why should you be able to inspect the defaults of a user-land utility via a kernel interface?

Comment: Related - [Where are NFS defaults specified?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/310180/100397)

Comment: @mosvy - what about the sentence: `Some  of  these  options could be enabled or disabled by default in the system kernel.  To  check  the  current  setting  see  the  options  in /proc/mounts.`?

Comment: That's alluding to the fact that the kernel may turn on some options by default, but it will show them explicitly in `/proc/mounts`, even if they're defaults. Eg. `relatime` (there was a [recent discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/581244) about it). If you mount a fs without any special options (no matter if you use the `mount(8)` program or use the `mount(2)` syscall directly), it will still have the `relatime` option in `/proc/mounts` or `/proc/mountinfo`. Maybe that manpage should be clearer and do less hedging around the facts -- go submit a documentation patch ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Simply check `mount` output ?

For example, given `~/tmpfile` a file where i created a ext4 filesystem:

```
~$ sudo mount -t ext4 -o defaults tmpfile /media/cdrom
~$ mount|grep /media/cdrom
tmpfile on /media/cdrom0 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

Comment: Shouldn’t it include all of `defaults` mount options given above? Yours only include `real` from that list.